# how I can to copy an existing file from my Pc to my solution directory?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to copy an existing file in my pc to a folder inside my data directory. I do this but it moves the file to myApp\bin\Debug\Imagenes and I would like to move it to myAp\Imagenes

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();            
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                File.Copy(openFileDialog1.FileName, Application.StartupPath + @"\Imagenes\imagen.jpg", true);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It does what you told it to: copy the fiel to `Application.StartupPath` which *is* `bin\Debug`. That's where your executable is

Comment: but then when I publish the application it doesn´t work. It can´t find the directory

Comment: @Mikelon85 - take a look at my proposed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction - to those who say Application.StartupPath will work. It is correct in what you say but the behaviour differs if you do a ClickOnce deployment! :)

Take a look here for a solution as documented:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8saf4wy(v=vs.110).aspx

Step 1 - check if it network deployed:

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
```

Step 2 - if so, then use the DataDirectory path:

```
ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory
```

if your app is not clickonce deployed, then this is where the "else" statement comes in and therefore use the default application.startup path. having this means your application is a bit more deployable friendly that can cater for both conditions - clickonce or not.

Comment: Thanks. I don´t know anything about click once so i will read it slowly ;)

Comment: no problem. we are all hear to learn! let us know if this works for ya.

Comment: anyway I was looking for something like I do to put my database path: SqlCeConnection miCon = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\base\entreno.sdf");

Comment: Sure. you are best to maybe, don't quote me, to remove the |DataDirectory| section and instead use the Application.Deployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory. But again, not sure as I have not tried this to see if |DataDirectory| string in the connectionstring takes into consideration the Deployment type of the app. But these types of delimiters are only for the SQL Engine and nothing else like this exists in general

Comment: Using ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory  it doesn´t work, when i publish the app it can´t find the directory. Anyway thanks .

Comment: What directory could it not find? How are you publishing it?

Answer (score 2):

> it moves the file to myApp\bin\Debug\Imagenes

This is what you are instructing to do here.

```
Application.StartupPath + @"\Imagenes\imagen.jpg"
```

[Application.StartupPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Gets the path for the executable file that started the application, not including the executable name. This is the reason it is moving to bin/Debug.

> I would like to move it to myAp\Imagenes

Then change the above path to what you want.

Comment: Correction - Application.StartupPath is correct in what you say but the behaviour differs if you do a ClickOnce deployment! :)

Comment: And how i can to put a relative path to my/App/Imagenes?

Comment: @Mikelon85 - take a look at my response/answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create the path using `String` functions:

```
string s = @"c:\newfolder\myApp\bin\Debug\Imagene"; //supposed path, you will put "Application.StartupPath" here
s = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(@"\bin")) + @"\Imagenes\imagen.jpg";
```

Now `s` is:

> c:\newfolder\myApp\Imagenes\imagen.jpg